# priority control with semaphore

Tags: objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Suppose I have a semaphore to control access to a dispatch_queue_t.
I wait for the semaphore (dispatch_semaphore_wait) before scheduling a block on the dispatch queue.

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore,DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
dispatch_async(queue){ //do work ; dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); }
```

Suppose I have work waiting in several separate locations. Some "work" have higher priority than the other "work".

Is there a way to control which of the "work" will be scheduled next?

Additional information: using a serial queue without a semaphore is not an option for me because the "work" consist of its own queue with several blocks. All of the work queue has to run, or none of it. No work queues can run simultaneously. I have all of this working fine, except for the priority control.

Edit: (in response to Jeremy, moved from comments)

Ok, suppose you have a device/file/whatever like a printer. A print job  consists of multiple function calls/blocks (print header, then print figure, then print text,...) grouped together in a transaction. Put these blocks on a serial queue. One queue per transaction.

However you can have multiple print jobs/transactions. Blocks from different print jobs/transactions can not be mixed. So how do you ensure that a transaction queue runs all of its jobs and that a transaction queue is not started before another queue has finished? (I am not printing, just using this as an example).

Semaphores are used to regulate the use of finite resources.
https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-09-25-gcd-practicum.html
[Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24)

The next step I am trying to figure out is how to run one transaction before another.

Comment: Running one transaction before another is exactly what serial queues are for.  You need to make each transaction a block on the queue.  Ditch your semaphore usage as that can easily lead to priority inversion.

Comment: ok, I'll google priority inversion and reconsider.

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the API here.  You should not be using semaphores to control what gets scheduled to dispatch queues.

If you want to serialize execution of blocks on the queue, then use a serial queue rather than a concurrent queue.

If different blocks that you are enqueuing have different priority, then you should express that different priority using the QOS mechanisms added in OS X 10.10 and iOS 8.0.  If you need to run on older systems, then you can use the different priority global concurrent queues for appropriate work.  Beyond that, there isn't much control on older systems.

Furthermore, semaphores inherently work against priority inheritance since there is no way for the system to determine who will signal the semaphore and thus you can easily end up in a situation where a higher priority thread will be blocked for a long time waiting for a lower priority thread to signal the semaphore.  This is called priority inversion.

Comment: Each transaction should be a single block in the queue.  You can execute all of the smaller blocks that are pieces of the transaction in a single block on the queue.

Comment: Then you are blocking the queue if you have are doing a lot work that doesn't involve the resource. Suppose you have to extract 1M rows from a database, calculate stuff (long work) and then return the answer to the database. You don't want to block the database queue while you are crunching numbers in the background.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be doing the processing on the db access queue.  Get the data from the db on the db queue, then run your processing on a background queue and then add the result on the db queue.  assuming you are trying to do read/write access, you should use a concurrent queue, using barriers for writes.

Comment: Lets take a step back: I have a queue for the resource and a separate queue for each transaction. On each transaction queue I scheduled blocks that are logically grouped together. (transaction.begin{}.then{}.then{}.done{} like a promise in functional programming) The target queue of the transaction queue is set to the resource queue. Because the DB needs to maintain data integrity, the transaction should run beginning to end. A job item of several transactions, including background work has its own background-queue. Job items can run concurrently, transactions can not.

Comment: Just create a block for your transaction which executes each of the other blocks directly.  Then enqueue this one block (the transaction) on your queue.  If your transaction modifies the resource and your queue is concurrent, make sure you use a barrier.  There is no reason for you to create a queue for each transaction.  Just execute them all in a single block.